# Signal handler in Linux using sigaction (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, signals, handler

I am trying to send SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2 signals between multiple processes using custom handler, but my handler does not work. It is not printing any debug messages or anything.

Here I am creating 8 processes and trying to set a custom handler using set_sigaction function:

```
int main(){
    pidArray = (int *)mmap(NULL, MMAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);//Self pid
    pidArray2 = (int *)mmap(NULL, MMAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);//Child pid
    counter = (int *)mmap(NULL, MMAP_SIZE2, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    counter[0]=0;
    counter[1]=0;
    pid_t pid, pid2;
    int counter = 1;
    pidArray[0]=getpid();
    pid = fork(); //1
    if(pid == 0){
        pid = fork(); //2
        if(pid != 0){
            pidArray[1]=getpid();
            pidArray2[1]=pid;
        }
        if(pid == 0){
            pid2 = getpid();
            pidArray[2]=pid2;
            pid=fork(); //4
            if(pid == 0){
                pidArray[4] = getpid();
                pid=fork(); //5
                if(pid==0){
                    pidArray[5] = getpid();
                    pidArray2[5] = 0;
                }
                else
                    pidArray2[4] = pid;
            }
        if(pid2 == getpid()){
            pid2 = fork(); //3
            if(pid2!=0){
                pid = setpgid(pid,pid2);
            }
            else{
                pidArray[3]=getpid();
                pid=fork(); //6
                if(pid==0){
                    pidArray[6]=getpid();
                    pid=fork(); //7
                    if(pid==0){
                        pidArray[7]=getpid();
                        pid=fork(); //8
                        if(pid!=0)
                            pidArray2[7]=pid;
                        else{
                            pidArray[8]=getpid();
                            pidArray2[8]=pidArray[1];
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        pidArray2[6]=pid;
                }
                else
                    pidArray2[3]=pid;
            }
        }        
        }
    }

    set_sigaction(SIGUSR1);

    sleep(5);

    if(getpid()==pidArray[1])
        kill(pidArray[0],SIGTERM);
    if(getpid()==pidArray[1]){
        send_signal(pidArray[1]);
    }
    sleep(100);
    return 0;
```

Here is set_sigaction function:

```
static int set_sigaction(int signo) 
{ 
    struct sigaction sa; 
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);  
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    return sigaction(signo, &sa, NULL);
}
```

And here is the handler:

```
static void handler(int signo, siginfo_t* si, void* ucontext){
    int k;
    int i;
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    for(i=1;i<9;i++){
        if(pidArray[i]==pid)
            k=i;
    }
    time_t rawtime;
    time ( &rawtime );
    cout << k << " " << pid << " Got USR1 " << ctime (&rawtime) << "\n";
    send_signal(getpid());
}
```

My send_signal function gives me this message, which means it send SIGUSR1 signal to the second process:

> 1 3156 Send USR1 Thu Jun 22 18:04:54 2017

I am thinking the problem is how I create multiple processes or how i set my handler.

Comment: You should be careful with POSIX signals: when a signal fire, it can interrupt everything (even kernel call). It means that, when handling the signal, you are potentially in an incorrect state, you may have data race, ... In the signal handler you should try to get out as fast as you can and you should most of the operation with side effect (like I/O).

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but if my handler has only a debug message. it still will not print it.

Comment: what do ``send_signal`` do ?

Comment: Are you sure their is no issue with giving ``sigaction`` the address of a local variable (which is not in ``main``) ?

Comment: You can only call a small set of async-signal-safe function from a signal handler. The functions this signal handler calls are not in that set.

Comment: Can you show us the code for `send_signal`?

Answer (score 0):

what does send_signal do ?
Try sending the signal using the kill function as :

kill(pidArray[1], SIGUSR1)

Comment: yeah, like that but for different processes